# Validation on radio button

Tags: javascript, radio-button

my validation is work on only one radio button and all left radio button its not working here is my code

```
    <script>
function xyz()
{
var x = document.getElementsByName("red");
//alert(x.length);

   for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
    {
        if (x[i].checked) {
        return true;
    }else{
    alert("fe");
    return false;
    }
  }
}
</script>

<form name="as" method="post" action="n.php">
<input type="radio" id="x1"   name="red">
<input type="radio"  id="x2"   name="red">
<input type="radio"   id="x3"  name="red">
<input type="radio"   id="x4"  name="red">

<input type="submit" value="button" onclick="return xyz()">
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Have you considered checking one of the buttons by default? That will save the need to validate

Answer (score 1):

You should try this.

```
function xyz()
{
    var x = document.getElementsByName("red");
    for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
    {
        if (x[i].checked) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    // No radio button checked, return false.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thank's yaar but could u please tell me what mistake i have done

Comment: Issue is when you iterating radio buttons, you have if/else, so if first radio button is not checked, it will come in else and return false, it will not check other radio buttons then. So first iterate all radio for checked, if anyone found it will return true.

Comment: thanks for giving me explaintion no my doubts get cleared if u don't mind can u give me your mail id so whenever i face problem in java script i can ask u and once again thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your function will return in either states after first run. To skip to next element of iteration you should use continue instead of return. See: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp. To iterate threw all elements you shoul do:

```
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].checked) {
        // Do something if checked
    } else {
        // Do something if not checked
        alert("fe");
    }
    // Continue to next element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
var checked = null;
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('correct');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
{
      if (inputs[i].checked) {
       checked = inputs[i];
   }
}
if(checked==null)
{
    alert('Please choose an option');
    return false;
}
else
{
    return confirm('Save As Correct Answer '+checked.value+'');
}
}   
</script>

<form method="post" name="Form" onsubmit="return validate()" action="">
<input type="radio" name="correct" id="correct" value="A">
<input type="radio" name="correct" id="correct" value="B">
</form>
```